# How to make Horizontal Scroll ListView inside the SingleChildScroll

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

I want to create a layout like this,
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sv2GI.jpg)

I want to create a flutter app which can scroll vertically and also some content of the app should scroll horizontally as describe in the picture. I used ListView with scroll horizontal inside the SingleChildScrollView but it not work. It hide the content Horizontal listView content and the content below the ListView.

So How to make this layout

Code I used,

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
              child: CustomizedAppBar(),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 30.0,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10,bottom: 5),
              child: Text(
                'Hello Jessica.',
                style: kArtistNamePlayScreen,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10,bottom: 40),
              child: Text(
                'Recommendeddd',
                style: kSongNamePlayScreen,
              ),
            ),
            //TODO Insert Carousel Here
            ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  height: 150,
                  width: 230,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.grey[100],
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage('images/Panini_l.jpg'),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                    boxShadow: [
                      new BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        offset: Offset(1.5,1.5),
                        blurRadius: 3,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Text(
              'Popular artists',
              style: kSongNamePlayScreen,
            ),
            Container(
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                    child: Container(
                      width: 60,
                      height: 75,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          image: AssetImage('images/Panini_l.jpg'),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        )
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SongList(
              songListSongName: 'Beautiful People',
              songListArtistName: 'Ed Sheeran',
              songListAvatarImage: AssetImage('images/beautiful_people_l.jpg'),
              heartClick: (){},
            ),
            SongList(
              songListSongName: 'Panini',
              songListArtistName: 'Lil Nas X',
              songListAvatarImage: AssetImage('images/Panini_l.jpg'),
              heartClick: (){},
            ),
            SongList(
              songListSongName: 'Do You Sleep',
              songListArtistName: 'Sam Samith',
              songListAvatarImage: AssetImage('images/Do_you_sleep_l.jpg'),
              heartClick: (){},
            ),
            SongList(
              songListSongName: 'Bad Guys',
              songListArtistName: 'Billie Eilish',
              songListAvatarImage: AssetImage('images/Bad_guys_l.jpg'),
              heartClick: (){},
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `ListView`, you can use `SingleChildScrollView` with `Row` as child. Then give the `SingleChildScrollView` the `scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal` Code:

```
//TODO Insert Carousel Here
      SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 150,
              width: 230,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey[100],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage('images/Panini_l.jpg'),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
                boxShadow: [
                  new BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    offset: Offset(1.5, 1.5),
                    blurRadius: 3,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `ListView` with horizontal scroll, it has to be wrapped inside a `Container` or `SizedBox` with a specific height.

Using `ListView.builder` could be more efficient, here is a quick example:

```
final _items = List.generate(20, (e) => e);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    body: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text("A"),
          SizedBox(
            height: 100.0,
            child: ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: _items.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  print('$index');
                  return SizedBox(
                    width: 150.0,
                    child: Center(child: Text('${_items[index]}')),
                  );
                }),
          ),
          Text("B"),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

You could see the prints in the console, indicating the items are created only when they're scrolled onto the screen.